# On applying commands to groups of lines from stdin

Tags: command-line, text-processing, zsh

The Unix package [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/examples/) supports the application of several summarizing operations to *groups* of input lines.  For example<sup>1</sup>, here `datamash` is used to compute the sums of column 2 for each value in column 1:

```
$ cat example.csv
1,10
1,5
2,9
2,11
$ datamash -t, -g 1 sum 2 < example.csv
1,15
2,20
```

Although `datamash` supports a wide range of functions besides `sum` (including `mean`, `stddev`, `median`, `iqr`, `min`, `max`, etc.), it is not extensible, AFAICT.  IOW, `datamash` does not support any mechanism for the user to supply his/her own summarizing function.

My question here boils down to: how can this group-wise application of commands be implemented generically on `zsh`<sup>2</sup>?

---

Below is an attempt to specify the question more precisely.  (Hopefully this attempt at precision won't render the question incomprehensible.)

First, suppose that `foo` stands for a (possibly composite) command that emits to stdout lines with the following structure:

*i* *separator* *payload<sub>i<sub>j</sub></sub>*

...where *i*, the "group index", is some integer, *separator* is some constant separator sequence (e.g. `,`, or `$'\t'`), and *payload<sub>i<sub>j</sub></sub>* is some arbitrary text (including the terminating newline).  Moreover, assume that the group index *i* ranges from 1 to *N*, and that the lines in this output are sorted according to the group index.

For every integer 1 ≤ *k* ≤ *N*, let the "*k*-th group" refer to the content consisting of the segments *payload<sub>k<sub>j</sub></sub>* of all the lines (in `foo`'s output) where the group index is *k*.

Next, suppose that `bar` stands for a (possibly composite) command that reads lines from stdin and emits *a single line* to stdout.

Now, let *result*<sub>*k*</sub> denote the output of applying `bar` to the *k*-th group, and let `X<bar>` stand for some shell construct that invokes `bar`.

I'm basically looking for a construct `X<bar>` such that the pipeline

```
foo | X<bar>
```

emits to stdout lines of the form

*i* *separator* *result*<sub>*i*</sub>

---

EDIT:

Supposing that *separator* is just `,`, then the following seems to do what I want

```
TMPFILE=$( mktemp )
SEPARATOR=,
LASTGROUPID=
foo | (cat; echo) | while IFS= read -r LINE
do
    GROUPID=${LINE%%$SEPARATOR*}
    if [[ $GROUPID != $LASTGROUPID ]]
    then
        if [[ -n $LASTGROUPID ]]
        then
            echo -n "$LASTGROUPID$SEPARATOR"
            cat $TMPFILE | bar
        fi
        LASTGROUPID=$GROUPID
        : > $TMPFILE
    fi
    PAYLOAD=${LINE#*$SEPARATOR}
    echo $PAYLOAD >> $TMPFILE
done
rm $TMPFILE
```

Basically, this use `$TMPFILE` to collect the lines in the next group.  (I'd prefer to avoid the temporary file, but I don't know how to do it.)

Now I need to figure out a way to implement this as a function that can take the expression denoted by `bar` as an argument, and use it robustly in the construct given above.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>This example is adapted from one given in the `datamash` man page.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>Although I am primarily interested in `zsh`, I have a secondary interest `bash` case as well.</sup>

Comment: `awk` and `gnuplot` are not an option?

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky: I've edited my post to give a better idea of the sort of thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't sound to me like a job for a shell. I'd do it in `perl`/`python`/`ruby`... though here `awk` may be enough:

```
$ cat sum
paste -sd + - | bc
$ sort -t , -k 1,1 input | awk -F, -v cmd=./sum '
   function out() {printf "%s,", l;close(cmd)}
   NR>1 && $1 != l {out()}
   {print $2 | cmd; l=$1}
   END {if (NR) out()}'
1,15
2,20
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've got the idea of what you're looking for: a script analogous to those producing the distribution from a set of samples, but with more accumulation options. I wrote an `awk` script for that.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Kg_QLltwbNU21zbHFMY1hnSjQ

It is not exactly what you want but the overlap must be significant. First - indices may be not only integer, second - the only accumulation method is summation. But since it is just a script, you can modify it as you like more easily than say C program.

Finally, such scripts are only applicable if the data set is small enough, for larger sets it is too slow! So a more specialized package is preferable (`R` etc.).

P.S. To add other accumulators, replace `+=` with a custom function (a la "monad").